# How to open two SQLite contexts on the same DB in different modes?

Tags: c, sqlite

I'm trying to use an in-memory SQLite DB and simultaneously need 2 contexts (one read-only, the other read-write). What seems to be happening is that the mode of the first context is used by all following contexts regardless of what mode they are are asked to use.

I have code that does approximately the following:

```
char *err;
sqlite3 rw, ro;
int flags = SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE | SQLITE_OPEN_URI;

sqlite3_open("file::memory:?cache=shared", &rw, flags);
sqlite3_open("file::memory:?cache=shared&mode=ro", &ro, flags);

// works as expected
sqlite3_exec(rw, "CREATE TABLE t (a TEXT)", NULL, NULL, &err);

// works as expected
sqlite3_exec(ro, "SELECT 1", NULL, NULL, &err);

// !!!!!!! Expected to fail but doesn't ??????????
sqlite3_exec(ro, "INSERT INTO t (a) VALUES ('a')", NULL, NULL, &err);
```

- If I reverses the first 2  lines then the `CREATE` statement fails.
- I've also tried using `SQLITE_OPEN_READONLY` rather than `&mode=ro` but it makes no difference.

---

Edit:

From [further](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/open.html#coreuriqueryparameters) [reading](http://www.sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html) it looks like doing an in-memory DB isa "mode" and so is not totally orthogonal to the `ro` vs. `rw` "modes".

Other things that don't work:

```
int flags = SQLITE_OPEN_URI;
sqlite3_open("file::memory:?cache=shared&mode=rw", &rw, SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE | flags);
sqlite3_open("file::memory:?cache=shared&mode=ro", &ro, SQLITE_OPEN_READONLY | flags);
```

and

```
int flags = SQLITE_OPEN_URI;
sqlite3_open("file::memory:?cache=shared", &rw, SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE | flags);
sqlite3_open("file::memory:?cache=shared", &ro, SQLITE_OPEN_READONLY | flags);
```

Answer (score 2):

tl;dr; It can't be done. Shared cache implies shared access modes, and first open wins.

After talking with a "expert" the conclusion I came to is that `SQLITE_OPEN_READONLY` and `SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE` are not security attributes and are not to be interpreted as *"Open the DB to allow ..."* but rather *"Open the DB assuming the underlying file is ..."* or alternatively, *"Don't fail if the file is read only"*.

The silent promotion still seems to be a bug but but is consistent with the intent. OTOH the intent doesn't seem to be well expressed in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

At first glance it looks like the OPEN_READWRITE flag is overriding the mode=ro in the URI.
Try replacing the second open with:

```
sqlite3_open("file::memory:?cache=shared&mode=ro", &ro,SQLITE_OPEN_URI);
```

Comment: That gives an immediate "out of memory" from the second `sqlite3_open_v2`. -- Also from some of the text in the docs, it seems that URI parameters can only restrict things from what the flags set.